# Do I need to have a using statement with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Can I use with Entity Framework:

```
private MyDbContext _context;

public ControllerName(MyDbContext context)
{
    this._context = context;
}
```

or should I use something like:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetSomething() 
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        //Some code
    }
}
```

When I have a using statement it wants me to pass in options for the `DbContext`. I am not exactly sure what options it wants me to pass in.

Comment: Does your `using` statement compile? If so, then the `MyDbContext` type implements `Disposable`. Most disposable objects should be disposed soon after use. So, ... yes.

Comment: Are you using asp.net core?

Comment: I am using asp.net core

Comment: My startup.cs gives a default db connection. So that is why I am wondering if I should pass another connection string as the options, or should I just use the _context that I already initialize in the constructor.

Comment: Both of these methods; `IServiceCollection.AddDbContextPool<T> / IServiceCollection.AddDbContext<T>` will register the context as a scoped service. The service container will dispose of all scoped instances when the scope is disposed. asp.net-core creates a scope for the lifetime of each request.

Comment: Both approaches are viable depending on the lifetime of each instance. DbContext instances should not be too long-lived (usually for one service call), passing around the same context instance for some long-running process may lead to subtle issues (like modified tracked entities being returned instead of fresh data) or in extreme cases even introduce memory leaks. Also, contexts that track a lot of data will generally perform worse than empty ones.

Answer (score 2):

It depends...

### Should I create my own DbContext?

The reason for the using statement when using the DbContext is because you want to keep the DbContext alive for a short period. The DbContext holds an open connection with the database and it remembers the fetched items, so you can change the properties of the fetched items one by one, without having to fetch the data from the database again.

This is a powerful optimization. The disadvantage however is, that if the database changes while your dbContext is still alive, the data in your dbContext gets out of sync with the actual data in your database.

Hence it is wise not to keep your dbContext alive for a longer time. The using block makes sure that whatever happens, `Dispose()` is called when leaving the block, even after exceptions. It is similar to the destructor in C++, which is automatically called as soon as the variable gets out of scope.

Whether you should create a class that has the DbContext as input or whether you should create your own DbContext depends on your class.

Do you want that your user (= software, not the operator) decides which database should provide the data that your class needs to query: let your user provide the dbContext, and let him Dispose it. Note: your user must be aware of this, and not keep your class alive for a longer period (think of seconds).

User:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(...))
{
    MyClass myObject = new MyClass(dbContext);

    var fetchedData = myObject.FetchData();
    ProcessFethedData(fetchedData);
}
```

Usually you don't want to burden your users with this. Consider to create a Disposable class that uses the `...` in the constructor. You can create the dbContext:

```
class MyDbContext: IDisposable
{
    private readonly MyDbContext dbContext;

    public MyClass(string nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        this.dbContext = new MyDbContext(nameOrConnectionString);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.dbContext?.Dispose();
    }

    public Customer FetchCustomer(int customerId)
    {
        return dbContext.Customers.Find(customerId);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using (var myDbContext = new MyDbContext(...))
{
    Customer customer1 = myDbContext.FetchCustomer(2);
    Customer customer2 = myDbContext.FetchCustomer(3);
    ...
}
```

Advantage: your customer won't have to know anything about your database, and about the method you are using to access it: is it entity framework? or are you using plain old SQL? Or maybe you are not using a database at all, but a CSV file!

The problem is: your user still has to remember your `nameOrConnectionString`, and he has to Dispose you after usage. He also has to know not to keep you open for a longer time.

On the other hand: it might be handy not to have to recreate the database connection again between fetching the two customers.

A third solution, which is mostly used is creating a class that will create and dispose the dbContext per method. If users forget to Dispose you, then the DbContext won't be kept open longer than needed.

Note: since you've hidden that you are using entity framework, or even that it is a database, give it a name that says: I am a class that can store data for a longer period of time:

```
class MyRepository
{
    private readonly string nameOrConnectionString;

    public MyClass(string nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        this.nameOrConnectionString = nameOrConnectionString);
    }

    public Customer FetchCustomer(int customerId)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(this.nameOrConnectionString)
        {
            return dbContext.Customers.Find(customerId);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var repository = new MyRepository(...)
Customer customer1 = repository.FetchCustomer(2);
Customer customer2 = repository.FetchCustomer(3);
```

Users can keep your repository alive for a longer period of time. The disadvantage is that per call the DbContext is created. Usually creating a dbContext is not time consuming, but keep it in mind: if you regularly need to fetch several items, consider creating a method to do this in one go. But then again: shouldn't you make methods for everything that you do "regularly"?

### The constructor of DbContext

DbContext has two constructors. An Empty one, that takes its connection string from the config file, or one with a connection string.

If everyone in your application should use the same database (and thus the same connection string), put the connection string in the app.config. [Microsoft about connection strings in DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/connection-strings)

If there are several databases that are to be controlled by the same DbContext, your creators must tell you which connectionstring they should use:

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    // Default constructor uses DbConnectionString from app.config
    public MyDbContext() : base()
    {
       ...
    }

    // only provide non-default constructor if users want to tell you which database to use
    public MyDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Hey bro, this really helped. I am using entity framework with identity as an authentication system with Jwt tokens. This pretty much answered my question thank you.

Comment: your code samples seem messed up - constructor names don't match class names. I think `MyDbContext` should really be named `MyClass`, which should also be reflected in the usage example. Or its dbContext field should not be of type `MyDbContext` but rather of another class that inherits from `DbContext`, one or the other

Answer (score 1):

You can use your context with both approaches. 1st option is with Dependency Injection for IoC. I have used it along with Repository in the following way:

**Repository**

```
public class ProductRepository : RepositoryBase<product>, IProductRepository
{
        public ProductRepository(RepositoryContext repositoryContext) : 
           base(repositoryContext)
        {
        }
        public IEnumerable<product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return FindAll().ToList();
        }
 }
```

**RepositoryBase**

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
        protected RepositoryContext repositoryContext { get; set; }
        public RepositoryBase(RepositoryContext repositoryContext)
        {
            this.repositoryContext = repositoryContext;
        }
        public IQueryable<T> FindAll()
        {
            return this.repositoryContext.Set<T>().AsNoTracking();
        }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class ProductController : ControllerBase
{
        private IRepositoryWrapper _repository;
        public ProductController(IRepositoryWrapper repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }
        
        public IActionResult ProductList()
        {
            var products = _repository.products.GetAllProducts();
        }
}
```